# Query to collapse records if record is substring and falls in a time interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, postgresql-8.0

I have the below events data:

```
events table

event_id | timestamp         | label
--------------------------------------------------
1        |2021-11-15 10:23:54| so
1        |2021-11-15 10:24:30| software
2        |2021-11-15 10:24:54| software Engineer
3        |2021-11-15 10:23:54| test
3        |2021-11-15 10:24:31| test eng
3        |2021-11-15 10:24:54| test Engineer
2        |2021-11-16 10:26:54| software Engineer and Test
```

I want to collapse this result set to the below result set.

```
Result:

event_id | timestamp         | label
----------------------------------------------------------
2        |2021-11-15 10:24:54| software Engineer
3        |2021-11-15 10:24:31| test Engineer
2        |2021-11-16 10:26:54| software Engineer and Test
```

Basically, I want to remove all the records that are substring of any records in future timestamp and have occurred in less than 3 mins interval.

In the above example:
`so` and `software` is removed because `software Engineer` is seen in the later timestamp, which is within 3 minutes interval.

`event_id` isn't necessarily always same.

Is this something possible using a query?

I know that it is easy to do using a program/script. Still, I would like to know how this can be done using a query.

Comment: The description of the algorithm is inconsistent. According to it, the row with `software Engineer` should also be removed.

Comment: Event with `software Engineer and Test` label comes the next day and not within 3 mins interval. `2021-11-16 10:26:54`. Hence this record doesn't overshadow the `software engineer`

Comment: Are you really using Postgres 8?  That would rule out window functions.

Comment: I am using redshift :) Which uses Postgres 8 

Comment: @BikasKatwal - OK, my oversight, sorry. Postgres 8 is archaic. In modern Postgres you could use a window function.